# Record Video While Playing Music on iPhone flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, audio, camera

I am trying to record a video(with sound) while background music will play over headphones in flutter. It is working in Android but but iOS devices(above iOS 14.0) the audio is playing through speakers as soon as video recording starts.

I am using :

1. **just_audio: ^0.9.16
2. audio_service: ^0.18.1
3. camera: ^0.9.4+3**

if I start the audio player before I start video recording the audio stops automatically.

and if I do the opposite,

```
await _cameraController!.startVideoRecording().then((value) {
                                 _audioHandler.play();
                                });
```

then the audio plays over speakers even headphones are connected.

Is there any Solution for this issue in flutter?

Comment: have you found any solution to this?